# Cakephp Distinct Matching Associated Table

Tags: distinct, matching, cakephp-3.0

I'm trying to filter data in associated table by using the matching() function.
The records are returned and i get all the Applicants that are purchased by the current customer. But i still get duplicate values for Applicants.

Tables -> applicants, purchases, applicants_purchases with belongsToMany associations on Purchases & Applicants.

This is what im trying to do.

```
$this->listConditions = ['Purchases.customer_id' => $user['customer_id']];
$query = $this->Applicants->find();
$query->matching('Purchases', function ($q) {
    return $q->select(['Applicants.id'])->distinct(['Applicants.id'])->where($this->listConditions);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind, i placed the select & distinct on the wrong end.

Ofcourse needs to be placed at the find() call like this.

```
$query = $this->Applicants->find()
   ->select(['Applicants.id'])
   ->distinct(['Applicants.id']);

$query->matching('Purchases', function ($q) {
    return $q->where($this->listConditions);
});
```